# Services Views and combine different field values into one?

Tags: views, services

I got a site with a profile2 type and a content type that uses the same field containting coordinates (field_coordinates).

I'm using Services Views to show these coordinates in JSON but this is where I ran into some problem. I want only one field set of these coordinates visible, but I have to chose the relationship of the field: either no releatinship shows the node coordinates, or the relationship with the profile shows the profiles coordinates.

There will never be two sets of coordinates per output node (in one case the are requested from the node, and the other case from the profile). The JSON output cant show two fields with the same label so I have to have two different names: one for profile coordinates and one for node coordinates.

**The issue is that I want only one coordinate field, and therefore added a global text field, where I put both of the place holders from the other coordinates. But this global text field output wont show in my Services view. Why is that?**

Answer (score 0):

Try taking one field and hiding it with views then if the next field is empty pull that one in there?
[image]

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer to the issue but this seems like it could be a workaround.

Comment: I cant hide it. It still shows..

Comment: I've added a (hopefully) helpful image to my answer. Any field in any view should have this option.